# How to replace data value(js) with a datatable value?

Tags: django, python-3.x, canvas, datatable, chart.js

Python 3.6.3
django==1.11.3
bootstrap4

I am trying to create a bar chart with data retrieved from a datatable.
how to map data(lables, data) values to datatable in a chart js file.
Assuming that hard-coded data exists as a datatable, how do you write a js file?

Please tell me how.

html

```
<div class="col-lg-6">
  <div class="card bar-chart-example">
    <div class="card-header d-flex align-items-center">
      <h4>Bar Chart Example</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="card-body">
      <canvas id="barChartExample"></canvas>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

chart js

```
var barChartExample = new Chart(BARCHARTEXMPLE, {
        type: 'bar',
        data: {
            labels: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July"],
            datasets: [
                {
                    label: "Data Set 1",
                    backgroundColor: [
                        'rgba(51, 179, 90, 0.6)',
                        'rgba(51, 179, 90, 0.6)',
                        'rgba(51, 179, 90, 0.6)',
                        'rgba(51, 179, 90, 0.6)',
                        'rgba(51, 179, 90, 0.6)',
                        'rgba(51, 179, 90, 0.6)',
                        'rgba(51, 179, 90, 0.6)'
                    ],
                    borderColor: [
                        'rgba(51, 179, 90, 1)',
                        'rgba(51, 179, 90, 1)',
                        'rgba(51, 179, 90, 1)',
                        'rgba(51, 179, 90, 1)',
                        'rgba(51, 179, 90, 1)',
                        'rgba(51, 179, 90, 1)',
                        'rgba(51, 179, 90, 1)'
                    ],
                    borderWidth: 1,
                    data: [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40],
                }
            ]
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [DataTables API](https://datatables.net/reference/api/data())

To get the data from behind the DataTable:

```
var dtapi = $('#node_containing_datatable').DataTable();
var dtdata = dtapi.data(); // this is a ref to the DT API
var dtdata_array = dtdata.toArray(); // this is a real javascript Array
```